# Azure resource graph query - getting data on VMs

Tags: azure-resource-graph

I am new to Azure resource graph query.
I would like to use resource graphy query to find out information on virtual machines.

Is it possible to create a query to get a list of  Virtual machines that have been deleted for a specified period? The scope is for all subscriptions.

Thanks,

buddd

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can filter by the TargetResourceType as virtualmachines & change type as Delete. This way you get all deletions happened within 30days(I guess)